# Can I skip BlocBuilder render in some case?

Tags: flutter, loading, bloc

There's a screen that have a bloc `MyBloc myBloc`

In the screen's build method, it's like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyCustomLoadingStack( //My custom widget to have the main content below the loading widget
        _buildContent(context), //My main content
        _buildLoading(context)); //My loading on top
}
```

And my 2 method:

```
Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
 return Column(children: <Widget>[
      OtherWidgetOne(),
      OtherWidgetTwo(),
      BlocBuilder<MyEvent, MyState>(
          bloc: myBloc,
          builder: (BuildContext context, MyStatestate) {
            switch (state.type) {
              case MyStateList.doneWorking:
                return MyDataWidget(); // this content cares about displaying the data only
              default:
                return Container(); //otherwise display nothing
            }
          },
        )
]);
```

}

```
Widget _buildLoading(BuildContext context) {
 return BlocBuilder<MyEvent, MyState>(
          bloc: myBloc,
          builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
            switch (state.type) {
              case MyStateList.loading:
                return LoadingView(); //This _buildLoading cares the loading only
              default:
                return Container(); //If it's not loading the show nothing for the loading layer
            }
          },
        )
}
```

My problem is when the content is currently showing data. When I `yield MyState(type: MyStateList.loading)` to show the loading when doing something else (like load more for the data which is currently showing). Both `BlocBuilder` are called and then the `_buildContent(context)` show nothing because it doesn't meet the `MyStateList.doneWorking` condition. And of course the `_buildLoading(context)` shows the loading on an empty content bellow.

Is there anyway I can skip the BlocBuilder inside `_buildContent(context)` to keeps showing the current data and still have the loading on top?

I though about having a Widget to contains the data or empty `Container()` to use in the default case of the `_buildContent(context)` but it doesn't make sense to me because they may re-render the same widget.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! Is there a reason why you're using BlocBuilder instead of StreamBuilder?

To show nothing while the data is loading and auto populate the data once it's loaded, I typically do the following:

```
   Widget _buildLoading(BuildContext context) {
     return StreamBuilder<Model>(
              stream: bloc.modelStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) return _buildErrorWidget(snapshot.error, context);

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return DesiredWidget()
    } else {
    return LoadingView()
    }
}
```

I haven't seen your BloC file but you may have to add a couple lines like the following:

```
final _modelFetcher = BehaviorSubject<Model>();
Stream<Model> get modelStream => _modelFetcher.stream;

Function(Model) get changeModelFetcher => _modelFetcher.sink.add;


@override
  void dispose() async {
    await _modelFetcher.drain();
    _modelFetcher.close();
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: At first, I use `StreamBuilder`, I call `_isLoadingStreamController.sink.add(true)` (or `false`) every time I need to load or not. But I read somewhere that if I use like that, it's like method call, and it's no longer event based bloc, that's why I use BlocBuilder to handle the state. I'm kinda confuse between those two. Maybe I can use `BlocBuilder` for the main content and `StreamBuilder` for the loading widget. But in that case, `BlocBuilder` is not needed anymore because it handles only one case when data is null or not. Then I can use `Streambuilder` for it, or even error popup,...

Answer (score 0):

There is a pullrequest beeing discussed to fix this problem right now:
https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/315?fbclid=IwAR2x_Q1x5MIUUPE7zFRpjNkhjx5CzR0qiRx-P3IKZR_VRGEp3eqQisTthDo

For now, you can use a class for a more complex state. This can be something like:

```
class MyState extends Equatable {
  final bool isLoading;
  final List<MyData> data;
  bool get hasData => data.isNotEmpty;

  MyState(this.isLoading,this.data) : super([isLoading,data]);
}
```

I use Equatable (https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) for easier isEqual implementation.

```
Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(children: <Widget>[
    OtherWidgetOne(),
    OtherWidgetTwo(),
    BlocBuilder<MyEvent, MyState>(
      bloc: myBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, MyStatestate) {
        if (state.hasData) {
          return MyDataWidget(); // this content cares about displaying the data only
        } else {
          return Container(); //otherwise display nothing
        }
      },
    )
  ]);
}

Widget _buildLoading(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<MyEvent, MyState>(
    bloc: myBloc,
    builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
      if (state.isLoading) {
          return LoadingView(); //This _buildLoading cares the loading only
      } else {
        return Container(); //If it's not loading the show nothing for the loading layer
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Downside of this appraoch is, that the datawidget will redraw, even tho the data doesnt change. This will be fixed with the mentioned pullrequest.

Comment: From the link you provided, I see this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc_extensions which may comes in handy while we are waiting for the fix. Thank you for your info.

Comment: Nice find, didn't know of that one. Looks usefull